# Stomp lib for python giving TypeError

Tags: python-2.7, stomp

I'm tring to use `stomp.py` for consume messages from ativemq.
Now when I  try set-up it gives me:

```
TypeErrorTypeError: subscribe() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

This my code is :

```
conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.start()
conn.connect()
conn.subscribe(destination=config['queue_name'], ack='auto')
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in a *dictionary* with configuration values, making that *one* argument:

```
conn.subscribe({destination=config['queue_name'], ack='auto'})
```

See the [`Stomp.subscribe()` documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/stompy/stompy.stomp.html#stompy.stomp.Stomp.subscribe).